# Render custom pretty_value in rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

Im trying to render custom output as formatted_value on show page. Thats what i have:

```
register_instance_option :formatted_value do
    data_modules.map do |dm|
      dm_value = value[dm.name].presence || {}
      dm.fields.map do |field|
        dm_field_value = dm_value[field.name].presence || ''
        "#{field.label}: #{dm_field_value}"
      end
    end.flatten.join(", ")
  end
```

data_modules are models, that contains some information about what fields i should render, so i render only field that user have in data_modules. No need to understand what algorithm does, we need just `"#{field.label}: #{dm_field_value}"` line.
So now i become a string with key: value items, but i want at least render every item in new line. dm_field_value might be jsonb value, i want it prettify to.

I already tried "/n" and symbols for new line.

Also tried to create array of

tags and render it like bindings[:view].tag(:div, <array of p`s>), but have no luck.
bindings[:view] would be ideal case, i can do whatever i want with it. (style, any tags)

Tried render it like separate partial, but i need access to data_modules.

Any ideas how to do it with pretty_value and bindings[:view].tag?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to use render method of bindings[:view]. There is ability to use custom partial in :pretty_value field and pass params to partial through locals. The whole solution looks like this:

```
bindings[:view].render partial: '<my_partial>', locals: { data_fields: content }
```

It allows to do any logic that i want and pass any data to partial, then render any haml or erb html.